# How can I calculate the dual norm in this case?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

We define $E$ the space of continuous functions as $x: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, endowed with the norm for $x \in E$:

$$\|x\|_{\infty} = \max_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)|$$

It is further defined $T : E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

$$T(x) = x(0) - \int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt$$

My question is how to calculate $\|T\|_{E^*}$,
I could show that $\|T\|_{E^*}\leq 2$, but I don't know how to prove the other inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the norm of a linear operator $T$ is lower bounded via evaluating it on a specific element $x_0$ (or a sequence $(x_n)_n$) of unit norm, i.e.
$$
\|T\|_{\rm op}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|\geq \|Tx_0\|
$$
or
$$
\|T\|_{\rm op}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|\geq \sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|Tx_n\|\,.
$$
For your operator $T$ maximizing $Tx$ amounts to maximizing $x(0)$ and minimizing $\int_0^1 x(t)\,dt$.
Because $x$ has to be from the closed unit sphere in $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{\rm sup})$, obviously, neither $x(0)$ nor $\int_0^1 x(t)\,dt$ can exceed $1$. Thus showing $\|T\|_{\rm op}\geq 2$ amounts to the following:

> *Goal:* Find a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of continuous functions $:[0,1]\to[-1,1]$ such that $x(0)=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|Tx_n\|= 2$.

*Edit:* The answer of @diracdeltafunk gives a good hint as to how one could construct such a sequence of functions!

Comment: thanks, now i can do it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to show that $\lVert T \rVert \geq 2$ would be to give an example of some $f \in E$ such that $\lVert f \rVert = 1$ and $\lvert T(f) \rvert \geq 2$. However, by your previous work, when $\lVert f \rVert = 1$ we must have $\lvert f(0) \rvert \leq 1$ and $\lvert \int_0^1 f(x) \; dx \rvert \leq 1$, so this would force (WLOG) $f(0) = 1$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) \; dx = -1$. There is a measurable function with this property, namely
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &: x = 0 \\ -1 &: x > 0\end{cases}$$
but this function is not continuous. Indeed, no continuous function $f \in E$ can satisfy these conditions.

So, we must abandon the easy approach and appeal directly to the definition of $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{E^*}$. To show that $\lVert T \rVert \geq 2$ means to find, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, an example of some $f_{\varepsilon} \in E$ such that $\lVert f_{\varepsilon} \rVert = 1$ and $\lvert T(f) \rvert \geq 2-\varepsilon$. In other words, it's ok to be off by a small error ($\varepsilon$), as long as the error can be made arbitrarily small!

Can you modify the non-continuous function above to complete the proof?

Comment: thanks, now i can do it